# Proving a vector space is, again, a vector space with respect to a new addition-law

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(V,+, \cdot)$ be a vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V $ a linear transformation. Let another addition-law in $V$ be defined as $\oplus: v \oplus w = T(v+w) = Tv+Tw$.

Prove that $(V, \oplus, \cdot)$, the scalar multiplication remains the same, is a vector space iff $T$ is the identity map $T(x) = x$.

I think I have the $\leftarrow$ direction: Assume $T$ is the identity map. So $r(v \oplus w) = rT(v+w) = T(r(v+w))) = T(rv+rw) = T(rv) + T(rw) = rv + rw$. So it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. (I won't go on to prove the rest of the properties.) So $V$ is a vector space. Feel free to correct/change, etc.

However, I'm not sure about the other direction.

Edit: I'm also a little unsure to the $\leftarrow$ direction. I need to prove that $rv + rw$ is $\in V$. All I've done is stated it.

Comment: "To prove a vector space is a vector space"? Weird. Perhaps you meant **a new** addition $\;\oplus\;$ is defined as ...etc., and then you have to show that $\;(V\,,\,\oplus)\;$ is a vector space? And apparently with the same product by scalars as originally.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $0$ must again be the neutral element. Then, consider $v \oplus 0 $.

Added: for the converse direction there is no need to check all the axioms. Just say if $T $ is the identity then $u \oplus v = Tu + Tv= u +v$ for all $u,v$ and by assumption $V$ with $+$ is a vectorspace.

Comment: $v \oplus 0 = T(v + 0) = T(v)+ T(0) = T(v)$. What am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: Yes, and on the other hand as $0$ remains the neutral element and thus $v \oplus 0 = v$, so $Tv = v$ as desired.